# Toggle between horizontal and vertical scrolling

Tags: java, user-interface

I'am making a Java based website and I want to know that is it possible so that a user can choose that whether he/she wants horizontal or vertical scrolling. If yes than kindly tell me the way for it.......

Comment: Java based? Or do you mean javascript based?

Comment: @tbodt I mean java based i.e through JSP and servlets